# Scala^Z3 (Z3 Version 3.2) and parsesmtlib2string(...) not working

Tags: scala, z3

While trying to implement a test using parsesmtlib2string I hit an error:

```
println("Hello World!");
var smtlib2String = ""
smtlib2String += "(declare-fun x () bool)" + "\n"
smtlib2String += "(declare-fun y () bool)" + "\n"
smtlib2String += "(assert (= x y))" + "\n"
smtlib2String += "(assert (= x true))" + "\n"
//  smtlib2String += "(check-sat)" + "\n"
//  smtlib2String += "(model)" + "\n"
smtlib2String += "(exit)" + "\n"

val cfg = new Z3Config
val z3 = new Z3Context(cfg)

z3.parseSMTLIB2String(smtlib2String)
```

When uncommenting "Check-sat" I get "unknown". 
When uncommenting "model" I get "unsupported".

Using F# with Z3 3.2 it would just give me a Term back, but in Scala the return type is Unit. I looked through the Z3-C API but didn't find a good example on how to use ist.

So, what is the best way to get a model using smtlib2string?

Btw: Using Scala^Z3 and building a Z3AST works just fine and I can get a model using .checkAndGetModel(). The SMT-LIB2 Code above works fine with the F# .NET parsesmtlib2string method.

Using one of "getSMTLIBFormulas, getSMTLIBAssumptions, getSMTLIBDecls, getSMTLIBSorts" yields "Error: parser (data) is not available".

Using "getSMTLIBError.size" yields "0".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parseSMTLIB2[...]` methods should indeed have returned a `Z3AST`, thanks for reporting the problem. This is fixed in [scalaz3-3.2.b.jar](https://github.com/downloads/psuter/ScalaZ3/scalaz3-3.2.b.jar). Now regarding the use of the SMT-LIB 2 parser, I'm myself new to this, so Leo should perhaps confirm, but my understanding is that you should only use it to parse formulas, not to issue commands such as `(check-sat)`.

Here is an example that works for me:

```
import z3.scala._
val smtlib2String = """
  (declare-fun x () bool)
  (declare-fun y () bool)
  (assert (= x y))
  (assert (= x true))"""

val ctx = new Z3Context("MODEL" -> true)
val assertions = ctx.parseSMTLIB2String(smtlib2String)
println(assertions) // prints "(and (= x y) (= x true))"
ctx.assertCnstr(assertions)
println(ctx.checkAndGetModel._1) // prints "Some(true)", i.e. SAT
```

Now if you want to programmatically recover the model for `x`, my understanding is that the only way to do it is to create a symbol for `x` *before* parsing and to pass it to the parser, using the overloaded definition of the `parseSMTLIB2[...]` method. Here is how you do it:

```
val ctx = new Z3Context("MODEL" -> true)
val xSym = ctx.mkStringSymbol("x") // should be the same symbol as in the SMT-LIB string
val assertions = ctx.parseSMTLIB2String(smtlib2String, Map(xSym -> ctx.mkBoolSort), Map.empty)
ctx.assertCnstr(assertions)
val model = ctx.checkAndGetModel._2
val xTree = ctx.mkConst(xSym, ctx.mkBoolSort) // need a tree to evaluate using the model
println(model.evalAs[Boolean](xTree)) // prints "Some(true)"
```

Hope this helps.

(Again, there may be a simpler way to do this, but I'm not aware of it. The parsing methods are directly bound to their C equivalent and the [only example I could find](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group__capi__ex.html#ga748ec8e9525340e9237dee62cd589672) doesn't show much.)

Comment: Great Job! You also feature a function called ".checkAndGetAllModels()" for which I haven't even found a .NET or C equivalent... and it works just fine for me. How do you do that? Many Thanks. Levent Erkok asked for this feature in another post: "Z3: A better way to model?"

Comment: Philippe is correct, the function `parseSMTLIB2String` is supposed to be used to parse formulas. Commands such as as `check-sat` are ignored by this command.

Comment: The checkAndGetAllModels function simply adds the negation of the previous models to the context, using pushes and pops, nothing too fancy. Btw, you probably shouldn't try to push new constraints between two calls to the resulting iterator.